# How is [DataMember] used with Image?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have the following code in a WCF service:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Bitmap))]
[KnownType(typeof(Image))]  
public class CompositeType {
Image FImg = null;
public Image Picture {
  get {
    return FImg;
  }
  set {
    FImg = value;
  }
}
```

If I add [DataMember] to the public Image, then the Service Reference gets broken in another solution.

```
[DataMember]
public Image Picture{
  get {
    return FImg;
  }
  set {
    FImg = value;
  }
}
```

My question is how do I use [DataMember] and Image at the same time? I know I can use a byte array and am currently doing so and then formatting / converting it in the client that calls my service, but I'd rather bind to the Image instead of having to convert a byte array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In WCF how do I return a class that contains a System.Drawing.Image property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767864/in-wcf-how-do-i-return-a-class-that-contains-a-system-drawing-image-property)

Comment: @Yuck - Similar to that one. I actually read that one before and am currently using part of its answer related to converting to byte array and tagging that as DataMember. However, I'm trying to find a way to not have to create the byte array.

Comment: From the accepted answer to that question: *"One way or another, you'll need to turn it into a byte[] or a Stream to get it over the wire, and rehydrate it as an image."*

Comment: Why don't you want a stream or a byte[]? If it'd be posible your wcf service will only ever be useable by .net clients. You should have a really good reason you want this :).

Comment: @David - One potentially less appealing approach that you *could* consider (though not as good as the streaming approach), is to return a base64 encoded string of the image. You're messages will be 33% larger but at least you won't have to stream a byte array.

Comment: @M.Babcock You don't have to stream the `Byte[]`. You just need to convert the `Image` into `Byte[]` before passing it to or from the service. Not hard, just not as magical as having WCF handle serialization for you.

Comment: @Yuck - That is nice to know (considering I've never had to do anything like it in the past), but David seems pretty adament that he doesn't want to use the `byte[]` at all so my comment still stands (just ignore the streaming part).

Comment: @M.Babcock He wants to use `[DataMember]` so he doesn't have to do serialization. I don't think it matters whether that's to a `Byte[]` or Base64 `String`. I understand his question and sympathize with what he wants to do, but unfortunately `Image` is more than just image data which is what causes built-in WCF serialization to break.

Comment: @the_ajp - I'm trying to do databinding in a Silverlight client that calls the wcf. I'm currently allowing columns to autogenerate, which leads to one column showing "System.Byte[]" as its data. 

I want that column to show an image instead. I added a DataGridTemplateColumn to the grid and have it bound to the same data with a Converter that takes the byte[] and recreates the image. However, I now have two columns for the same data.

Comment: @Yuck - I think I'm doing what the accepted answer says for the other question. I'm just trying to see if there's another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using the AutoGeneratingColumn event handle on the clientside (the Silverlight application calling my WCF service) works also. Not necessarily an answer to my question, but I think it's useful to know. I would've added as comment, but code is too long.

```
private void dgResults_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
      if (e.PropertyType == typeof(byte[])) {
        e.Column.Header = e.Column.Header + "_D";
        // Create a new template column.
        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        templateColumn.Header = e.Column.Header + "_E";
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["imgTemplate"];
        templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["imgTemplate"];
        // ...
        // Replace the auto-generated column with the templateColumn.
        e.Column = templateColumn;

      }
    }
```

The Resources["imgTemplate"] are created in the .XAML file in Silverlight and this code is in its code-behind.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BinaryArrayToURIConverter x:Key="binaryArrayToURIConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="imgTemplate">
      <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding GraphicBytes,Converter={StaticResource binaryArrayToURIConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

The local: refers to part of the main XAML declaration:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<your namespace here>"
```

The code for BinaryArrayToURIConverter:

```
public class BinaryArrayToURIConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);
      BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
      image.SetSource(ms);
      return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```